# Problema con imágenes en proyectos publicados c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, poo

Tengo un proyecto en su fase final, en una parte tengo que recuperar el nombre de una imagen de la base de datos, y en base a este nombre busco en la carpeta *Resources* el nombre de esa imagen, y la muestra en un *picturebox*.

Las imágenes las añadí mediante el diseñador, en propiedades, recursos y añadir imágenes, cuando hice esto me creó una carpeta llamada *resources*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con este código abro la imagen

```
string ruta = "Resources/" + nombreimagen;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ruta);
                this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Cuando compilo en modo DEBUG me funciona todo bien, pero cuando publico el proyecto me dice que no encuentra las imágenes...
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
¿Me falta algún paso?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: lo pudiste resolver ? me puedes decir como lo resolviste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiene que dar click derecho sobre la imagen y seleccionar "Properties" y en la opción "Copy To Output Directory" seleccionar "Copy always"

[image: Propiedades de la imagen]

Esto asegurara que siempre se cree y se copie esa imagen tanto en debug como en release.

Una mejor forma para acceder a la ruta de la imagen sería:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string nombreArchivo = Path.Combine(dir, @"Resources\imagen.png");
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(nombreArchivo);
```

Comment: Hice los pasos que me dijiste y aún así no encuentra las imágenes, probé también en Acción de compilación poniendo "content", luego con "resources" y con "incrusted resource" y sigue igual...

Comment: problema resuelto, muchas gracias